# Non internal alternative for Gradle's JavaExecAction

Tags: plugins, gradle

In my custom Gradle task I use `org.gradle.process.internal.JavaExecAction` (implementation `org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction`) as a helper to run Java processes. As it is internal, it can always be changed in a breaking way or even be removed in a future version.

The alternatives I thought of are some kind of dirty too:

- Inheriting from JavaExec task
- Using AntBuilder
- Back to the roots: Runtime.exec

In my opinion, JavaExecAction is a really nice helper that does exactly what I need. Is there something similar that's part of the official Gradle API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the custom task [JavaExec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html). It's part of the public API and the recommended way of executing Java.